# Keep your Phonegap app running in the background using Phonegap build cli-6.5.0

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I am being trying to implement the background feature in Phonegap to check for the current location in Android and iOS. There are several plug-ing that claim to do the job. However. I have tried most of them in the last 2 weeks, but most of them does not work. Apprently the majoriety of them are updated. They dont seen to support phonegap-build cli-6.5.0. Everything works fine, exept when i try to implement the plug-ing the las

The last plug-in i used, seen it see to be the most promising was https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git. But When I build the app and run the code i get and error saying the the object that the plug-in supposed to create was not create and there for the undefined backgroundMode

This is the list of all the plug-ing I currently have in case the could be incompatibility

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm"/> <!-- required -->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm"/> <!-- required -->
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-pushipc" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" />
<plugin spec="cordova-background-location-services"  source="npm"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information"   source="npm"  />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-barcodescanner" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />
```

Any help of adivse

Comment: `When I build the app and run the code i get and error saying the the object that the plug-in supposed to create was not create and there for the undefined backgroundMode` you are probably calling the plugin before the deviceready event has fired.

Comment: Hi DaveAlden, this comment lead me to fix my problem. Apperently the object is create when the app goes to background mode. I was trying to use object during the active life of the controller